# How to read and write into another text file having numbers, strings and special characters

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, python-3.10

I have a text file with the below numbers, strings and special characters.

```
63
148
77
358765
Orange
44.7
14
%
61
80
**
```

How to read the file and write into another file with only odd numbers.

Here's my rough code

```
with open("Odd-Numbers.txt", "r") as i:

with open("Output.txt", "w") as o:

    odds = []

            for num in i:
        try:
            num = int(num)
            if num % 2:
                odds.append(num)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    for line in i:
        output.write(line)
        print(line, end = "")
```

It is giving me the error: **invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Mango\n'**

Comment: Please fix the indentation issues. Also, `input` is not the best choice of variable name, because it is a built-in. I would suggest you change that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `int(num)` you have to make sure, that num is always a number, otherwise string as 'Mango' will give you the `ValueError`.

For now, you can try this:

```
with open("Odd-Numbers.txt", "r") as input_file:

    with open("Output.txt", "w") as output_file:

        odds = []

        for num in input_file:
            try:
                num = int(num)
                if num % 2:
                    odds.append(num)
            except ValueError:
                pass

        for line in odds:
            output_file.write(str(line) + '\n')
```

That code will ignore any values, that cannot be integers. But it's not good practise to use `input` as variable name. Never use built-in function names like that.

Comment: I have changed the variable name from input to i. And tried the above code with try, but the output file is empty.

Comment: I've edited my answer for full solution.